# tf-idf vectorizer for multi-label classification problem

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf, multilabel-classification, tfidfvectorizer

I have a multi-label classification project for a large number of texts. 
I used the tf-Idf vectorizer on the texts (train_v['doc_text']) as follows:

```
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train_v['doc_text']) 
X_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_counts) 
x_train_tfidf, x_test_tfidf, y_train_tfidf, y_test_tfidf = train_test_split(X_tfidf_r, label_vs, test_size=0.33, random_state=9000)
sgd = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', random_state=42, max_iter=25, tol=None, fit_intercept=True, alpha = 0.000009  )
```

now, I need to use the same vectorizer on a set of features (test_v['doc_text'])to predict the labels.
however, when I use the following

```
X_counts_test = count_vect.fit_transform(test_v['doc_text']) 
X_tfidf_test = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_counts_test) 
predictions_test = clf.predict(X_tfidf_test)
```

I get an error message

```
ValueError: X has 388894 features per sample; expecting 330204
```

any idea on how to deal with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using `fit_transform` here which make the `TfidfTransform()` fit on the `test data` and then transform it.

Rather use `transform` method on it.

Also, you should use `TfidfVectorizer`

In my opinion the code should be:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_transformer = TfidfVectorizer()
# X_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train_v['doc_text']) 
X_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(train_v['doc_text']) 
x_train_tfidf, x_test_tfidf, y_train_tfidf, y_test_tfidf = train_test_split(X_tfidf, label_vs, test_size=0.33, random_state=9000)
sgd = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', random_state=42, max_iter=25, tol=None, fit_intercept=True, alpha = 0.000009  )

# X_counts_test = count_vect.fit_transform(test_v['doc_text']) 
X_tfidf_test = tfidf_transformer.transform(test_v['doc_text']) 
predictions_test = clf.predict(X_tfidf_test)
```

Also, why are you using `count_vect` I think it has no usability here and in `train_test_split` you are using `X_tfidf_r` which is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: hi, Thanks a lot for your help. the 'X_tfidf_r'  is simply 'X_tfidf'. I was just trying something that didn't work. however, when I use transform on test_v['doc_text'], I am getting this error 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' Do you have any suggestions on how to over come this? thanks

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. however I neede to use the count_vec to do so. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Does the above-provided solution help you? and also post your answer also.

Comment: yes it helped, especially in using transform instead of fit transform. my solution is the same as the original one except for the transform  issue. thanks.